# array/ math table error: Missing $ inserted. Extra }, or forgotten $

Tags: tables, overleaf

I'm getting 7 errors at the same time, comming from the same thing, in Overleaf which are described by the compiler as:

```
Missing $ inserted.
Extra }, or forgotten $.
Missing } inserted.
```

I'm quite a newcomer to LaTeX and I know this error is very common, but I'm unable to solve it. I've been able to narrow down the source of the errors to this table:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
\toprule
T \; (\pm   0.1 ^\circ C) &
  \Delta t \; (\pm   0.25s) &
  \eta \;   (g \cdot cm^{-1} \cdot s^{-1}) &
  \eta_{Laden} \; (g \cdot cm^{-1} \cdot s^{-1}) &
  \eta_{Fax} \; (g \cdot cm^{-1} \cdot s^{-1}) \\
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{27.6   \pm 1.2}     & 14.48         & 8.1 \pm \, 1.4        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3 \\
                                    & 14.50         & 8.1 \pm \, 1.4        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3 \\
                                    & 13.44         & 7.5 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.1 \pm \, 1.2        & 7.2 \pm \, 1.2 \\
                                    & 13.33         & 7.5 \pm \, 1.2        & 7.1 \pm \, 1.2        & 7.1 \pm \, 1.2 \\
                                    & 14.29         & 8.0 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.6 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.6 \pm \, 1.3 \\
& & & & \\
\multirow{5}{*}{38.1 \pm 1.4}       & 7.16          & 4.0 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.8 \pm \, 0.6        & 3.8 \pm \, 0.7 \\
                                    & 7.00          & 3.9 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.7 \pm \, 0.6        & 3.7 \pm \, 0.6 \\
                                    & 7.39          & 4.1 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.9 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.9 \pm \, 0.7 \\
                                    & 7.93          & 4.4 \pm \, 0.8        & 4.2 \pm \, 0.7        & 4.2 \pm \, 0.7 \\
                                    & 7.72          & 4.3 \pm \, 0.7        & 4.1 \pm \, 0.7        & 4.1 \pm \, 0.7 \\
& & & & \\
\multirow{5}{*}{48.25 \pm 1.25}     & 4.48          & 2.5 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.59          & 2.6 \pm \, 0.5        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.26          & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.20          & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.2 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.2 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.24          & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4 \\
& & & & \\
\multirow{5}{*}{53.25 \pm 1.25}     & 3.38          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.32          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.44          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.4        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.30          & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.36          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
$}
\caption{\eta vs T}
\end{table}
```

the packages I use are these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, main=spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Comment: One problem is `\caption{\eta vs T}`.  You need `\caption{$\eta$ vs $T$}`

Comment: please next time post a test document as in the posted  answer not disconnected fragments which make it harder to see the issue.

Comment: unrelated but avoid using `\resizebox` on tables it makes it impossible to have consistent fonts sizes and rule widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The use of math in `\caption` needs `$` delimiters.
2. The use of math in `\multirow` needs `$` delimiters.

I also took the liberty of setting `Fax` and `Laden` in `\mathrm`

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english, main=spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$
\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
\toprule
T \; (\pm   0.1 ^\circ C) &
  \Delta t \; (\pm   0.25s) &
  \eta \;   (g \cdot cm^{-1} \cdot s^{-1}) &
  \eta_{\mathrm{Laden}} \; (g \cdot cm^{-1} \cdot s^{-1}) &
  \eta_{\mathrm{Fax}} \; (g \cdot cm^{-1} \cdot s^{-1}) \\
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{$27.6  \pm 1.2$}     & 14.48         & 8.1 \pm \, 1.4        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3 \\
                                    & 14.50         & 8.1 \pm \, 1.4        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.7 \pm \, 1.3 \\
                                    & 13.44         & 7.5 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.1 \pm \, 1.2        & 7.2 \pm \, 1.2 \\
                                    & 13.33         & 7.5 \pm \, 1.2        & 7.1 \pm \, 1.2        & 7.1 \pm \, 1.2 \\
                                    & 14.29         & 8.0 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.6 \pm \, 1.3        & 7.6 \pm \, 1.3 \\
& & & & \\
\multirow{5}{*}{$38.1 \pm 1.4$}       & 7.16          & 4.0 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.8 \pm \, 0.6        & 3.8 \pm \, 0.7 \\
                                    & 7.00          & 3.9 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.7 \pm \, 0.6        & 3.7 \pm \, 0.6 \\
                                    & 7.39          & 4.1 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.9 \pm \, 0.7        & 3.9 \pm \, 0.7 \\
                                    & 7.93          & 4.4 \pm \, 0.8        & 4.2 \pm \, 0.7        & 4.2 \pm \, 0.7 \\
                                    & 7.72          & 4.3 \pm \, 0.7        & 4.1 \pm \, 0.7        & 4.1 \pm \, 0.7 \\
& & & & \\
\multirow{5}{*}{$48.25 \pm 1.25$}     & 4.48          & 2.5 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.59          & 2.6 \pm \, 0.5        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.26          & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.20          & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.2 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.2 \pm \, 0.4 \\
                                    & 4.24          & 2.4 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4        & 2.3 \pm \, 0.4 \\
& & & & \\
\multirow{5}{*}{$53.25 \pm 1.25$}     & 3.38          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.32          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.44          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.4        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.30          & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
                                    & 3.36          & 1.9 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3        & 1.8 \pm \, 0.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
$}
\caption{$\eta$ vs $T$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well thank you so very much!! I've been 2 hours trying to figure out what was happening, wish I could return the favour.

Comment: @J.Pottiez You are welcome. Once you garner enough site reputation (15 I think), you will be able to click the up-arrows to the left of questions and answers (except your own) that you believe contain valuable content.  And I thank you for the check mark "acceptance" of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, here are some improvements using the `siunitx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}, separate-uncertainty = true}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2(2)] S[table-format=2.2] *{3}{S[table-format=1.1(2)]}}
\toprule
{T} &
  {$\Delta t$} &
  {$\eta$} &
  {$\eta_{\text{Laden}}$} &
  {$\eta_{\text{Fax}}$} \\
{($\pm$ \SI{0.1}{\celsius})} &
  {($\pm$ \SI{0.25}{\s})} &
  {(\si{\g\per\cm\per\s})} &
  {(\si{\g\per\cm\per\s})} &
  {(\si{\g\per\cm\per\s})} \\
\midrule
                                    & 14.48         & 8.1(14)        & 7.7(13)        & 7.7(13) \\
                                    & 14.50         & 8.1(14)        & 7.7(13)        & 7.7(13) \\
27.6(12)                            & 13.44         & 7.5(13)        & 7.1(12)        & 7.2(12) \\
                                    & 13.33         & 7.5(12)        & 7.1(12)        & 7.1(12) \\
                                    & 14.29         & 8.0(13)        & 7.6(13)        & 7.6(13) \\
\addlinespace                                                                                     
                                    & 7.16          & 4.0(07)        & 3.8(06)        & 3.8(07) \\
                                    & 7.00          & 3.9(07)        & 3.7(06)        & 3.7(06) \\
38.1(14)                            & 7.39          & 4.1(07)        & 3.9(07)        & 3.9(07) \\
                                    & 7.93          & 4.4(08)        & 4.2(07)        & 4.2(07) \\
                                    & 7.72          & 4.3(07)        & 4.1(07)        & 4.1(07) \\
\addlinespace                                                                                     
                                    & 4.48          & 2.5(04)        & 2.4(04)        & 2.4(04) \\
                                    & 4.59          & 2.6(05)        & 2.4(04)        & 2.4(04) \\
48.25(125)                          & 4.26          & 2.4(04)        & 2.3(04)        & 2.3(04) \\
                                    & 4.20          & 2.4(04)        & 2.2(04)        & 2.2(04) \\
                                    & 4.24          & 2.4(04)        & 2.3(04)        & 2.3(04) \\
\addlinespace                                                                                     
                                    & 3.38          & 1.9(03)        & 1.8(03)        & 1.8(03) \\
                                    & 3.32          & 1.9(03)        & 1.8(03)        & 1.8(03) \\
53.25(125)                          & 3.44          & 1.9(04)        & 1.8(03)        & 1.8(03) \\
                                    & 3.30          & 1.8(03)        & 1.8(03)        & 1.8(03) \\
                                    & 3.36          & 1.9(03)        & 1.8(03)        & 1.8(03) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{$\eta$ vs $T$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't yet understand how {S[table-format=2.2(2)] S[table-format=2.2] *{3}{S[table-format=1.1(2)]}} works with uncertainties